# Rails - removing folder from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I accidentally unpacked a gem (paperclip) in my root folder.  Now I can't get rid of it to save my life.  I add it, remove, add it, stash it, try to check it out...nothing works.  I know I'm not providing much detail, but has anyone run into this issue before?  Rails env is 2.3.11.

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   paperclip-2.3.16/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: `rm -f /` ? No but seriously if you haven't checked it into source control yet just delete it and you should be fine.

Comment: yea, this ended up working sudo rm -rf paperclip-2.3.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do:

```
git rm -r --cached paperclip-2.3.16/*
```

You could also throw a `-f` on there before the `--cached` if you want, to try to **force** it.

I'm referring to this source:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html

Answer (score 0):

Since is not tracked yet, you can just do a `rm -rf paperclip-2.3.16` and it should remove it with no problems.